# Search vs Search & replace

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a piece of code in JavaScript that is supposed to replace all the occurrences of a char in multiple strings inside a JSON obj.

Not all of the strings contain the specific char, and we are talking about **a lot of strings**. So my question is: When talking about efficiency, is it best to make the replace or to search the string for the char and only if found make replace?

In other words:

```
var obj = ["str","str2","tr3","str","tr2","str3","str","s22tr2","str3","st","rtr2","str3","str","str2","str3","str","str2","str3","str","str2","str3","str","str2","str3","str","str2","str3","str","str2","str3","str","str2","str3","str","str2","str3","str","str2","str3"];
```

option 1:

```
for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++){
  if(obj[i].indexOf("s")!=-1){
      document.write(obj[i].replace(/s/gi,"*"));
  }
}​
```

option 2:

```
for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++){
    document.write(obj[i].replace(/s/gi,"*"));
}​
```

Thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried testing your code in [JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/)?

Comment: It depends largely on how many of them will contain the char, which is why profiling is always the best approach.

Comment: `if(str1.indexOf("o"))` means "If the first character is not 'o'", so it almost certainly isn't what you want.

Comment: It also depends on the length of `str1`.

Comment: Length is unknown, and its incremental. Lets say that after 1 week it could be 1000 strings, and after 6 months 100000 or might as well stay 1000. That's why I'm looking for a "usually better" way

Comment: Should both 's' and 'S' be replaced in your example? I'm asking because of `/i` modifier.

Comment: Yes. It should replace both of them.

Comment: When replacing `/s/`, the implementation already searches the string for a `s`. If there is no `s`, it would be just as expensive as `indexOf`. If there is an `s`, then you're experiencing overhead of `indexOf` *and* regexp searching for the `s`. Of course, implementations are not required to do certain optimizations, but in your case I doubt whether it's worth using `indexOf`.

Comment: Be aware that you are only checking for 's' in option 1, not 's' and 'S'.

Comment: @pimvdb If I understand right, option 2 "normaly" would be the way to go. Am I correct?

Comment: @Phoenix: Yes, I would find that logical - but testing is the only way to know for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the number of elements in the obj and the size of each element with direct replace faster in most cases. What is by far the fastest for the sample you provided is "join and replace". Check this very lazy example:

```
var obj = ["str","str2","tr3","str","tr2","str3","str","s22tr2","str3","st","rtr2","str3","str","str2","str3","str","str2","str3","str","str2","str3","str","str2","str3","str","str2","str3","str","str2","str3","str","str2","str3","str","str2","str3","str","str2","str3"];
var b = obj.join(',');
b +=',' + b; //  * 2
b +=',' + b; //  * 4
b +=',' + b; //  * 8
b +=',' + b; //  * 16
b +=',' + b; //  * 32
b +=',' + b; //  * 64
b +=',' + b; //  * 128
obj = b.split(',');
var t1 = new Date().getTime();

for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++)
    if(obj[i].indexOf("s")!=-1 || obj[i].indexOf("S")!=-1)
        document.write(obj[i].replace(/s/gi,"*"));
    else
        document.write(obj[i]);
document.write('<br>');

var t2 = new Date().getTime();

for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++)
    document.write(obj[i].replace(/s/gi,"*"));
document.write('<br>');

var t3 = new Date().getTime();

document.write(obj.join('|').replace(/s/gi,"*").split('|').join('')); // see note
document.write('<br>');

var t4 = new Date().getTime();

alert((t2-t1) + ' vs ' + (t3-t2) + ' vs ' + (t4-t3));
```

Note: '|' represents a char (or even a tag) that is not included in the object elements and helps to avoid errors.

Pick and choose.

UPDATE:

Added capital S in 1st test.

Interesting case to explore: /s/gi.test vs indexOf

Comment: You need to check for the index of 's' or 'S' in the 1st test. Although the OP didn't specify this, they said in a comment that it should replace 's' or 'S'.

Comment: Thanks but I made a very lazy sample based on the provided code. I will add the 'S' which will make the first test worst.